# Python how do you get a particular part of code to run again

Tags: python-3.x

Okay so I'm very new to the programming world and have written a few really basic programs, hence why my code is a bit messy. So the problem i have been given is a teacher needs help with asigning tasks to her students. She randomly gives the students their numbers. Students then enter their number into the program and then the program tells them if they have drawn the short straw or not. The program must be able to be run depending on how many students are in the class and this is where i am stuck, I can't find a way to run the program depending on how many students are in the class. Here is my code

```
import random

print("Welcome to the Short Straw Game")
print("This first part is for teachers only")
print("")

numstudents = int(input("How many students are in your class: "))
task = input("What is the task: ")
num1 = random.randint(0, numstudents)
count = numstudents

print("The part is for students")  #Trying to get this part to run again depending on number of students in the class
studentname = input("What is your name:")
studentnumber = int(input("What is the number your teacher gave to you: "))

if studentnumber == num1:
     print("Sorry", studentname, "but you drew the short straw and you have to", task,)
else:
print("Congratulations", studentname, "You didn't draw the short straw")
count -= 1
print("There is {0} starws left to go, good luck next student".format(count))
```

Comment: Check out `range()` in a for loop

Answer (score 1):

[Read up on `for` loops.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Simply put, wrap the rest of your code in one:

```
# ...
print("The part is for students")

for i in range(numstudents):
    studentname = input("What is your name:")
    #...
```

Also, welcome to the world of programming! :) Good luck and have fun!

Comment: thank you so much that worked, but is there a way i can then run the whole program again. So if the teacher has another task that they want completed they can then run the program again ?

Comment: Exactly so. :) (Or you could wrap the entire program in a `while` loop so it effectively executes forever, but closing and restarting the program makes more sense.)